# How to use JSON array in Laravel

Tags: laravel

this itemArray is got in a controller

```
itemArray = \DB::select($sql);
```

@json($itemArray) on a blade file

it displays

```
[{"date":"2021-08-03 00:00:00","price":10000},
{"date":"2021-08-06 00:00:00","price":11400},
{"date":"2021-08-13 00:00:00","price":11400},
{"date":"2021-08-20 00:00:00","price":5700}]
```

I would like to use this array like this

```
@foreach($itemArray as $item)
{{$item["date"] }}
@endforeach
```

so that I can arrange all "date" in my blade html.

Is there anyone who knows how to fetch Date only from this JSON? array?

Comment: most basic way is just decode the json to array using `json_decode($items, true);` so you will get array of that json

Comment: Just as a sidenote, if you switch to the query builder rather than using a raw SQL query you can then use `->pluck('date')` to get an array of only the dates from the result set e.g. `DB::table('mytable')->pluck('date')` would get all dates from that table. Will also make your code much more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@foreach($itemArray as $item)
{{$item->date }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eloquent instead, you can add this to your model:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'itemArray' => 'array',
];
```

Then when accessing `itemArray`, you’ll get an array. When you write to it as an array, it’ll convert it to JSON to store it for you.

See [Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)